# Android: change tab order/position in TabWidget

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, tabwidget

In my Android TabWidget, I would like to be able to change the index of a tab such that the order or position of the tab is changed relative to the other tabs.  I don't see a way to do this in the documentation.  Anyone have any ideas?

I have a scrolling tab bar with the last tab on the right labeled with "+".  The user clicks this to create a new tab.  But the new tab is always being created to the far right and I want to insert the new tab just to the left of the "+" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [TabHost.java](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TabHost.java). You'll most likely need to roll your own TabHost and alter addTab to take an index and add it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks Berdon.  I looked at the code and I think I see what I would change in addTab to make this work.  However, I'm not great at java and I don't know if when you say "roll your own" you intend for me to copy-paste the entire class and make my changes (which I tried but my project didn't like import com.android.internal.R) or if you mean write a class that extends TabHost and write a new addTab method or override it (which I tried but when extended I don't think you can access the private members of the superclass).

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to copy/paste the whole shebang and make it work. Which may or may not be complex depending on the number of internal classes it references which you'll also have to copy into your package, along with all the references and convert them over to yours (ie. com.android.internal.R.xxx -> com.my.package.R.xxx).

Comment: To try to solve this problem I copied in TabWidget and ran into even more issues with this class trying to access things that it doesn't have access to in my project.  The other difficulty is that both TabHost and TabWidget reference a bunch of drawable and style resources that I don't want to try to replicate.  So for now I'm going to stick with keeping my "new tab" tab on the left edge.

Answer (score 0):

Can you extend the TabHost and add your own implementation to addTabWithIndex(). There are many datastructures inside TabHost which are private so extending might not entirely resolve your issue.

Comment: I tried, I failed.  The various sub datastructures got in the way